# How to Properly use Custom Class Generics

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to use Custom Generic class and interface.Im having problems to find a solution for the logic and code of my small Project.

THE BLUEPRINT INTERFACE

```
 public interface IDepartment<T>
    {
        T CreateAndGetValues(SqlDataReader dataReader);   

    }
```

THE POSSIBLE DTO

```
 public class Bank<T> : IDepartment<T>
    {
        public int LfdNr { get; set; }

        public string Kennung { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Straße { get; set; }

        public string PLZ { get; set; }

        public string Ort { get; set; }

        public DateTime TSCREATE { get; set; }

        public DateTime TSUPDATE { get; set; }

        public T CreateAndGetValues(SqlDataReader dataReader)
        {

            Bank<T> TheReturnObject = new Bank<T>();
            ThereturnObject.LfdNr = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader.GetValue(0));
            ThereturnObject.Kennung = dataReader.GetValue(1).ToString();
            ThereturnObject.Name = dataReader.GetValue(2).ToString();
            ThereturnObject.Straße = dataReader.GetValue(3).ToString();
            ThereturnObject.PLZ = dataReader.GetValue(4).ToString();
            ThereturnObject.Ort = dataReader.GetValue(5).ToString();
            ThereturnObject.TSCREATE = DateTime.ParseExact(dataReader.GetValue(6).ToString().Trim(), "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            ThereturnObject.TSUPDATE = DateTime.ParseExact(dataReader.GetValue(7).ToString().Trim(), "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return TheReturnObject;
        }                
    }
```

THE GENERAL DATABASE READER.

```
public class Mssql<T> where T :class, IDepartment<T>, new()
    {
        public List<T> ReadTable()
        {
            string sqlcommand = "Select * from Bank; ";
            List<T> TheListofObject = new List<T>();
            using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
            {
                cnn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlcommand, cnn))
                {
                    SqlDataReader dataReader;
                    try
                    {
                        dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

                        while (dataReader.Read())
                        {
                            IDepartment<T> Object = new T();
                            Object.CreateAndGetValues(dataReader);                            
                            TheListofObject.Add(Object);
                        }                        
                        return TheListofObject;
                    }                    
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                    dataReader.Close();
                }
                cnn.Close();
            }

        }
    }
```

THE MAIN PROGRAM

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mssql<Bank<T>> TEST = new Mssql<Bank<T>>();
            List<Bank<T>> TheList = TEST.ReadTable();

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
```

I am expecting that i can use a interface with a method where classes can inherit and return a new type of itself with the Type T and to pass the Type. So that the classes are not dependent that much to each other. And code can be reusable. I hope that is not confusing. Thanks

Comment: It *looks* like you're basically writing a basic ADO.NET/object mapper; I *strongly* recommend using established tools for this - consider Dapper, for example; your `ReadTable` could essentially be `Query<T>(...)`; but : you have posted some code; it isn't obvious to me what the actual question is. What part doesn't work in the way you'd like? Is there an error? Is something just... not what you want? Please be explicit so we understand what part you're actually asking about

Comment: It *looks* like the only bit you're missing is: `T Object = new T();` (instead of `IDepartment<T> Object = ...`) ?

Answer (score 1):

For this task I strongly recommend using an ORM. They are popular and mostly free. Stackoveflow runs on one of them.

Wikipedia's [List of object-relational mapping software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#.NET) gives 9 .NET examples as of Oct 2019.

Here is an example from Dapper's [doco](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

```
public class Dog
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float? Weight { get; set; }

    public int IgnoredProperty { get { return 1; } }
}

var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
var dog = connection.Query<Dog>("select Age = @Age, Id = @Id", new { Age = (int?)null, Id = guid });
```

If you add [Dapper.Contrib](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib) you don't even need to write the query if you want all records.

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // Works by convention
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

(...)

var cars = connection.GetAll<Car>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for your time guys.
I have found an answer with out using any tool to my Problem. And I would like to share it.

//THE BLUEPRINT INTERFACE

```
public interface IDepartment
    {
        Object GetAndReadValues(SqlDataReader dataReader);    

    }
```

// The Possible DTO

```
public class Bank : IDepartment
    {
        public int LfdNr { get; set; }

        public string Kennung { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Straße { get; set; }

        public string PLZ { get; set; }

        public string Ort { get; set; }

        public DateTime TSCREATE { get; set; }

        public DateTime TSUPDATE { get; set; }

        public void CreateAndGetValues(SqlDataReader dataReader)
        {
        }

        public Object GetAndReadValues(SqlDataReader dataReader)
        {

            Bank ThereturnObject = new Bank();
            ThereturnObject.LfdNr = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader.GetValue(0));
            ThereturnObject.Kennung = dataReader.GetValue(1).ToString();
            ThereturnObject.Name = dataReader.GetValue(2).ToString();
            ThereturnObject.Straße = dataReader.GetValue(3).ToString();
            ThereturnObject.PLZ = dataReader.GetValue(4).ToString();
            ThereturnObject.Ort = dataReader.GetValue(5).ToString();
            ThereturnObject.TSCREATE = DateTime.ParseExact(dataReader.GetValue(6).ToString().Trim(), "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            ThereturnObject.TSUPDATE = DateTime.ParseExact(dataReader.GetValue(7).ToString().Trim(), "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return ThereturnObject;


        }
```

//THE GENERAL DATABASE READER.

```
public class Mssql<T> where T :class, IDepartment, new()
    {            
        public List<T> ReadTable()
        {
            string sqlcommand = "Select * from Bank; ";
            List<T> TheListofObject = new List<T>();
            using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
            {
                cnn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlcommand, cnn))
                {
                    SqlDataReader dataReader;
                    try
                    {
                        dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

                        while (dataReader.Read())
                        {
                            IDepartment Object = new T();
                            object ReturnObject = Object.GetAndReadValues(dataReader);                            
                            TheListofObject.Add((T)ReturnObject);
                        }                        
                        return TheListofObject;
                    }
                    //Error handling with th DB must be handeld correctly with the specific error
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                    dataReader.Close();
                }
                cnn.Close();
            }

        }

    }
```

//THE MAIN PROGRAM

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mssql<Bank> TEST = new Mssql<Bank>();
            List<Bank> TheList = TEST.ReadTable();


            foreach (var item in TheList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.LfdNr);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Kennung);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Ort);
                Console.WriteLine(item.PLZ);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Straße);
                Console.WriteLine(item.TSCREATE);
                Console.WriteLine(item.TSUPDATE);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("");

            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
```

Comment: But... what use does this code have? You can't easily use it for another IDepartment. I'd strongly suggest to take Marc's comments at heart, and use an existing ORM instead of inventing your own. This will break as soon as you insert a new column, for example.

Comment: yes it will. But the task was not to use any tool and to use custom Generics.